# Openapi generator does not generate @XmlAttribute/@XmlElement annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am fiddling around with openapi at the moment and trying to create an endpoint that consumes a XML file. When creating the models with openapi however it seems all the XML annotations that I'm used to are missing. This is the openapi.yaml I'm using.

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  version: "1.1"
  title: xml test
  description: some xml test

servers:
  - url: 'http://localhost/:8080'

paths:
  '/test':
    put:
      operationId: testMethodNaming
      requestBody: 
        content:
          'application/xml':
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyRequest'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'OK'

components:
  schemas:
    MyRequest:
      type: object
      properties: 
        name:
          type: string
          xml: 
            attribute: true
```

The `MyRequest` schema is the thing in question now. Note that I declare the name property as a XML attribute. The generated class looks looks like this:

```
/**
 * MyRequest
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2019-03-12T15:32:37.070386+01:00[Europe/Berlin]")

public class MyRequest   {
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  public MyRequest name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  */
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")


  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    MyRequest myRequest = (MyRequest) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.name, myRequest.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class MyRequest {\n");

    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

I generated this using the spring-boot generator. I would have expected a `@XmlAttribute` annotation to be present above the name field. I would also have expected that there would be a `@XmlRootElement` on top of the class.

For some reason I cannot run the generated code right now, but it seems if I would send `<MyRequest name="foobar">` to the endpoint it would not be able to parse it with that model.

Did I miss some configuration option or anything so it generates the correct annotations?

Looking at the sourcecode of openapi the needed annotations are there

- [Class Header Template](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/xmlAnnotation.mustache)
- [Model Template (Line 24)](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is becoming more and more clear to me: right now, the generators of OpenAPITools , as well as it father SwaggerCodeGen, have json as primary target format. Xml is supported true, but more as an option and frankly quite badly.
I have recently discovered 3 bugs:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9052
- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2240
- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2243

To make it work, I had to customize myself the various [mustache templates](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java) in order to have correct xml annotations. The workaround is described in the first issue.

**Important: also make sure the `withXml` option is activated, so that the mustache Pojo template will produce the required xml annotations.**

Good luck.

Comment: Hm, if i look at the source the annotations I would need are there (see my edit). For some reason the class header and the annotation above the fields is just skipped while rendering the template

Comment: Did you set "withXml" to true in your (Maven or Gradle) config ?

Comment: No i didn't,... works now if you want edit your original answer or paste a new one so I can accept it, if someone else oversees this :)

Comment: Glad it's working ! I have updated my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the configOption "withXML" at the right place. It must be defined within the "configOptions":

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>openapi-generator-generate</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>some.yaml</inputSpec>
                <output>target/generated-sources</output>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <modelPackage>com.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>com.client</apiPackage>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    <withXml>true</withXml>
                    <library>resttemplate</library>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
<!--                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>-->
                    <java8>true</java8>
                    <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                    <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: does anybody understand why plugin authors introduced 'configOptions' block? it greatly confuses vs 'configuration' block.